# Real time feedback from dynamic created textbox(s)

Tags: jquery, html, angularjs

Python developer here trying to figure out some HTML.  I'm working on an internal tool that allows the user to create directories for projects.  So I've set up a method to dynamically add and remove text boxes that are used to build the file path.  But I'd like to display the file path being generated in real time.  For example is I add 3 boxes this would display a file path like so:  c:/box1Name/box2Name/box3Name

I'm not sure how to go about getting the data entered into those text boxes in real time.  Is this possible?

UPDATE:  So I've been educating myself a bit more and I cleaned up the code to make it all using AngularJS.  Hopefully this will make it easier to get help for what I want to do.  Basically I'd like to be able to add the values in the dynamic text boxes generated to the output below it.

Here is some test code as an example:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html>
    <head>
        <!-- Add Angular library -->
        <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.6.9/angular.min.js"></script>
        <!-- Add Local scripts -->
        <script type="text/javascript"> 
            var app = angular.module('myApp', []);
            app.controller('dynamicAddBoxesCtrl', function($scope) {
                $scope.boxSet = {
                    boxes: []
                };
                $scope.quest = {};
            
                $scope.boxSet.boxes = [];
                $scope.addNewBox = function() {
                    $scope.boxSet.boxes.push('');
                };
            
                $scope.removeBox = function(z) {
                    $scope.boxSet.boxes.splice(z, 1);
                };
            
                $scope.inbox1_model = "";
                $scope.inbox2_model = "";
            });
        </script>
    </head>   
      
    <body ng-app="myApp" style="background: #4b4b4b!important; color: #e5e5e5; margin:0 auto;">
        <div ng-controller="dynamicAddBoxesCtrl">
            <h1>Dynamic Form Fields Creation Plugin</h1>
            <input type="button" ng-click="addNewBox()" value="ADD DIRECTORY">
            <div>
                <form data-ng-repeat="field in boxSet.boxes track by $index">
                    <input ng-model="boxSet.boxes[$index]"></input>
                    <button ng-click="removeBox($index)"> &#10006 </button>
                </form>
            </div>
            <h1>Real-Time Update</h1>
            <div>
                Inbox1: <input type="text" ng-model="inbox1_model"><br>  
                Inbox2: <input type="text" ng-model="inbox2_model"><br>                      
                <br/>
                <strong>Output: {{inbox1_model + " " + inbox2_model}}
            </div>            
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: I see the HTML you are adding has `ng-model` on it - is this also used with an Angular 1.x application?  if so, you should do this within the angular controller and not rely on jQuery at all.

Comment: @ChrisBarr - To be completely frank, most of this code is scratched together from what I've learned via google searches.  I work mainly with Python so I'm not fully versed with HTML or any of the different libraries used.

That being said, I would love to not rely on jQuery but I'm not quite sure how to do this with just the angular  controller.

Comment: Post your angular controller here (or what you can) and I'm sure there's a way to make it work.  Also add the `angular` tag to this post.  Angular would be a far more elegant solution here, and it's usually always a bad idea to mix angular and jquery in the same project.

Comment: OK thanks for the suggestions.  As to the angular controller question, I am not even sure what that is (although I'm reading up on it now).  The code I posted is basically all I have at the moment.  It's boiled down to make it easier to post here, but there's nothing extra that has anything to do with AngularJS.

Comment: Hmm, well your code has a reference to `angular.min.js`, an `ng-app` and a few `ng-model`'s in there - so that's why I assumed it was angular.  If it's not angular, perhaps you just copy/pasted these from some angular examples elsewhere on the web.  If this is the case, you can remove these attributes without causing any harm

Comment: Hi Chris, I updated my code just using AngularJS.  Maybe that will make it easier to provide help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not entirely sure if this is what you were going for from the code you had, but based on your original question I think this will do it.

Basically you just want a UI to create an array of strings, and then present them below as a directory path, right?  You really did have the majority of the working code in place, but just needed to join all the array items together at the end to present them as a single string.

```js
angular.module('myApp', [])
  .controller('dynamicAddBoxesCtrl', function($scope) {
      $scope.boxes = ['foo', 'bar'];
      $scope.addNewBox = function() {
          $scope.boxes.push('');
      };

      $scope.removeBox = function(z) {
          $scope.boxes.splice(z, 1);
      };
  });
```

```css
code {
  background: #FEFEFE;
  border: 1px solid #CCC;
  padding: 1px 2px;
  border-radius: 3px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.6.9/angular.min.js"></script>
          
<div ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="dynamicAddBoxesCtrl">
    <h1>Dynamic Form Fields Creation Plugin</h1>
    <button type="button" ng-click="addNewBox()">Add Directory</button>
    <form data-ng-repeat="field in boxes track by $index">
        <input type="text" ng-model="boxes[$index]"/>
        <button ng-click="removeBox($index)"> &#10006; </button>
    </form>

    <hr/>
    <div ng-if="boxes.length > 0">
        <strong>Output</strong>: <code>C://{{boxes.join('/')}}</code>
    </div>
    <em ng-if="boxes.length === 0">Nothing added yet!</em>
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you!  This is exactly what I was looking for.  Thanks again for the learning opportunity.  You forced me to go back and rework what I had which gave me a much better understanding of the code.  :)

Comment: Glad i could help!